# How to format fractional seconds in POSIXct in r

Tags: r, posixct

I have read other questions regarding this topic but they do not seem to work on my dataset:

```
              Timestamp Bid.price Ask.price Bid.volume Ask.volume
 20070313 07:01:04:762  11.14122  11.14478   4.539397   1.891416
 20070313 07:01:07:608  11.13930  11.14670   1.277812   3.066750
 20070313 07:01:08:701  11.14095  11.14505   0.050396   0.050396
 20070313 07:01:11:275  11.14098  11.14502   0.226505   0.543613
 20070313 07:01:13:884  11.13930  11.14670   0.322856   0.774855
 20070313 07:01:16:588  11.13930  11.14670   0.405654   0.973569
```

I have tried:

```
as.POSIXct(fx[,1], format="%y%m%d %H:%M:%S:%OS3")
as.POSIXct(paste(fx[,1]), format="%y%m%d %H:%M:%S:%OS3")
as.POSIXct(paste(fx[,1]), format="%y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but all I get are `NA`s ...

How do I work around this?

Here is the dataset:

```
fx <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("20070313 07:01:04:762", "20070313 07:01:07:608", 
"20070313 07:01:08:701", "20070313 07:01:11:275", "20070313 07:01:13:884", 
"20070313 07:01:16:588"), Bid.price = c(11.14122, 11.1393, 11.14095, 
11.14098, 11.1393, 11.1393), Ask.price = c(11.14478, 11.1467, 
11.14505, 11.14502, 11.1467, 11.1467), Bid.volume = c(4.5393967628479, 
1.27781200408936, 0.0503959991037846, 0.226504996418953, 0.3228560090065, 
0.405654013156891), Ask.volume = c(1.89141595363617, 3.06675004959106, 
0.0503959991037846, 0.543613016605377, 0.774855017662048, 0.973568975925446
)), .Names = c("Timestamp", "Bid.price", "Ask.price", "Bid.volume", 
"Ask.volume"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can get the basics with `strptime(fx$Timestamp, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S:%OS')`, but I'm pretty sure it's butchering the fractional seconds, if they're important. You might need to replace that last `:` with a `.` so you can use `%OS`.

Comment: @alistaire It is removing the milliseconds, and according to the OP's title they seem to be important. One can use either `%S` or `%OS`, but to my knowledge not both. I agree that, unless some fancy package is used, it will probably be necessary to remove the last `:`. Then one could use `%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS` It may moreover be required to change the settings of `options(digits.secs)`.

Comment: Got it in one: `strptime(sub(':(\\d{3})$', '.\\1', fx$Timestamp), '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS')`

Comment: Thank you so much @alistaire . It was not working until I changed `options(digits.secs=3)` . You can add your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Timestamp` has a `:` between whole seconds and fractional seconds, and there isn't a time parsing string ("conversion specification", e.g. `%Y`) for fractions of seconds without the whole, you need to change the last `:` to a `.` so you can parse it with `%OS`. `sub` can take care of it, looking for

- a colon `:`
- followed by 3 digits `\\d{3}`, captured `(...)`
- followed by the end of the line `$`,

and replacing it with

- a period `.`
- followed by the captured group.

Further, if you want to *see* the fractional seconds that it's parsing, you'll need to set the `digits.secs` option:

```
options(digits.secs = 3)
strptime(sub(':(\\d{3})$', '.\\1', fx$Timestamp), '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS')
# [1] "2007-03-13 07:01:04.762 EDT" "2007-03-13 07:01:07.608 EDT" "2007-03-13 07:01:08.700 EDT"
# [4] "2007-03-13 07:01:11.275 EDT" "2007-03-13 07:01:13.884 EDT" "2007-03-13 07:01:16.588 EDT"
```

Note that `strptime` inserts the local timezone (`EDT` for me at the moment), but you can set that to whatever you like (or whatever it should be for your data) with its `tz` argument.